# Find frequency of digits in an int array in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, io, frequency

I am trying to write a function that takes the size of an array and an int array made up of digits as input and prints the frequency of each digit.

Sample input and output:

```
Input: [1,2,2,3,3,3]

Output:
1 occurs 1 times.
2 occurs 2 times
3 occurs 3 times.
```

Here is my attempt (not the most elegant):

```
void freq(int size, int numArray[]) {
    int one=0, two=0, thr=0, fou=0, fiv=0, six=0, sev=0, eit=0, nin=0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 1) {
                one+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 2) {
                two+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 3) {
                thr+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 4) {
                fou+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 5) {
                fiv+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 6) {
                six+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 7) {
                sev+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 8) {
                eit+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == numArray[j] && numArray[i] == 9) {
                nin+=1;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("1 occurs %d times.\n", one);
    printf("2 occurs %d times.\n", two);
    printf("3 occurs %d times.\n", thr);
    printf("4 occurs %d times.\n", fou);
    printf("5 occurs %d times.\n", fiv);
    printf("6 occurs %d times.\n", six);
    printf("7 occurs %d times.\n", sev);
    printf("8 occurs %d times.\n", eit);
    printf("9 occurs %d times.\n", nin);
}
```

This has problems. If I use the same example as above, this is what I get:

```
Input: [1,2,2,3,3,3]

Output:
1 occurs 0 times.
2 occurs 4 times.
3 occurs 9 times.
```

Comment: Use only one loop (keep `i` loop) and remove `numArray[i] == numArray[j]` everywhere

Comment: Consider using an array for holding the digit frequencies, such that `freqs[i]` is the frequency of the number `i`.

Comment: You seams to be at the begin of learning c. Personal advice: use a debugger, it's a really nice tool to learn! (and after to find bug). You can run step by step your program and see evolution of variables, it will help you to understand what code does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The nested loop approach makes no sense, you only need to look at each digit once to count it. And of course an array makes more sense to keep the counters:

```
void freq(int size, const int *numbers)
{
  unsigned int counts[10] = { 0 };
  for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
  {
    const int here = numbers[i];
    if(here >= 1 && here <= 9)
      counts[here]++;
  }
  for(int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
    printf("%d occurs %u times\n", i, counts[i]);
}
```

Comment: Incorrect input will corrupt the stack or cause memory access error, sample:  `arr[4] = {1,1,4097,2}; freq(4, arr);` – Alexey Voytenko

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko Sure, that's perhaps something to protect against, I added some code. Thanks.

Comment: The function should count digits? 0 should be included.

Comment: @AlexeyVoytenko I know, but it's not in the original code. Don't ask me why. :)

Answer (score 1):

your logic is flawed. what you want is to iterate **once** over the array and check each element. something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    if (numArray[i] == NUMBER)
       NUMBER_COUNTER ++;
.
.
.
```

Or, using your original code:

```
void freq(int size, int numArray[]) {
    int one=0, two=0, thr=0;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (numArray[i] == 1) {
                one+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == 2) {
                two+=1;
            }
            else if (numArray[i] == 3) {
                thr+=1;
            }
    }
    printf("1 occurs %d times.\n", one);
    printf("2 occurs %d times.\n", two);
    printf("3 occurs %d times.\n", thr);

}
```

Another solution that I think is more elegant is this:
create a new array with 9 elements (assuming you want to count frequencies of 9 digits...) and increment the slot of the found digit... something like this:

```
    void freq(int size, int numArray[]) {
    int freq_arr[size];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        freq_arr[ numArray[i] ] ++;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        printf("i: %d = %d\n", i, freq_arr[i]);
```

Comment: The last function does not check that numArray[i] is a valid index for freq_arr.
With wrong input it will corrupt memory: `arr[2] = {1,-19};`

Comment: From what I understood the OP's input is bounded, so no input check required

Answer (score 0):

What do you need the inner loop for? What you need is to look at each digit once in each iteration so as to count it. It is simpler than you think. Change your code to :

```
void freq(int size, int numArray[]) {
    int one=0, two=0, thr=0, fou=0, fiv=0, six=0, sev=0, eit=0, nin=0;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (numArray[i] == 1) 
            one+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 2)
            two+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 3) 
            thr+=1;      
        else if (numArray[i] == 4) 
            fou+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 5) 
            fiv+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 6) 
            six+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 7) {
            sev+=1;
        else if (numArray[i] == 8) 
            eit+=1; 
        else if (numArray[i] == 9) 
            nin+=1;
}
    printf("1 occurs %d times.\n", one);
    printf("2 occurs %d times.\n", two);
    printf("3 occurs %d times.\n", thr);
    printf("4 occurs %d times.\n", fou);
    printf("5 occurs %d times.\n", fiv);
    printf("6 occurs %d times.\n", six);
    printf("7 occurs %d times.\n", sev);
    printf("8 occurs %d times.\n", eit);
    printf("9 occurs %d times.\n", nin);
}
```

---

Another approach instead of keeping ten `int` variables as counters would be to keep an array of ten `int`s, like this :

```
void freq(int size, int numArray[]) {

    int i;
    int counters[10];
    //initialize the array's elements to zero
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        counters[i] = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if (numArray[i] = i)
            counters[i]++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void freq(int size, const int numArray[]) {
    int cnt[10] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
         if (0 <= numArray[i] && numArray[i] <= 9)
           cnt[numArray[i]]++;
    }
    // cnt = {0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
}

// test
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int arr[4] = {1,1,1,2};
    freq(4, arr);
    return 0;
}
```